# Permutation importance using a Pipeline in SciKit-Learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline

I am using the exact example from [SciKit](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/inspection/plot_permutation_importance.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-inspection-plot-permutation-importance-py), which compares `permutation_importance` with `tree feature_importances`

As you can see, a Pipeline is used:

```
rf = Pipeline([
    ('preprocess', preprocessing),
    ('classifier', RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42))
])
rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

**`permutation_importance`**:

Now, when you fit a `Pipeline`, it will *Fit all the transforms one after the other and transform the data, then fit the transformed data using the final estimator.*

Later in the example, they used the `permutation_importance` on the fitted model:

```
result = permutation_importance(rf, X_test, y_test, n_repeats=10,
                                random_state=42, n_jobs=2)
```

**Problem:** What I don't understand is that the features in the `result` are still the original non-transformed features. Why is this    the case? Is this working correctly? What is the purpose of the `Pipeline` then?

[image]

**`tree feature_importance`**:
In the same example, when they use the `feature_importance`, the results are transformed:

```
tree_feature_importances = (
    rf.named_steps['classifier'].feature_importances_)
```

[image]

I can obviously transform my features and then use `permutation_importance`, but it seems that the steps presented in the examples are intentional, and there should be a reason why `permutation_importance` does not transform the features.

Comment: I can see from the code that it iterates over the originals columns of X (`for col_idx in range(X.shape[1])`) and does the transformation inside the loop. Can't think of a particular case where this can go wrong, but that's what's happening

Comment: This frustrates me as well. I can't find an easy way to do permutation importance since everything is assembled into a pipeline. If I break out the preprocessor and transform BEFORE permutation, I get all sorts of headaches about column ordering for the labels. This could all be solved if the pipeline would be properly applied inside permutation_importance

Comment: @Josh, yes I decided to do the same. I transform the features and then pass the transformed vector to the pipeline.

Comment: Care to accept the (correct) answer?

Comment: how can you filter the boxplot to just the most important features?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. The way permutation importance works is to shuffle the input data and apply it to the pipeline (or the model if that is what you want). In fact, if you want to understand how the initial input data effects the model then you should apply it to the pipeline.

If you are interested in the feature importance of each of the additional feature that is generated by your preprocessing steps, then you should generate the preprocessed dataset with column names and then apply that data to the model (using permutation importance) directly instead of the pipeline.

In most cases people are not interested in learning the impact of the secondary features that the pipeline generates. That is why they use the pipeline here to encompass the preprocessing and modeling steps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess there is another reason too. one-hot encoding results in perfect multicollinearity and feeding the PI with multicollinear features can be misleading