# How do I get feature importances for decision tree pipeline that has preprocessing and classification steps?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, decision-tree, feature-engineering

I'm trying to fit Decision Tree model on UCI Adult dataset. I built the following pipeline to do so:

```py
nominal_features = ['workclass', 'education', 'marital-status', 'occupation', 
                'relationship', 'race', 'sex', 'native-country']

nominal_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')),
    ('ohe', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))
])

numeric_features = ['age', 'fnlwgt', 'capital-gain', 'capital-loss', 'hours-per-week']

numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('scaler', StandardScaler())
])

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('numeric', numeric_transformer, numeric_features),
        ('nominal', nominal_transformer, nominal_features)
    ]) # remaining columns will be dropped by default

clf = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('preprocessor', preprocessor),
    ('classifier', DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy', random_state=0))
])
```

I then fit my model by calling

```py
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Then, when I try to get feature importances,

```py
clf.named_steps['classifier'].feature_importances_
```

I get an array of shape (104,)

```py
array([1.39312528e-01, 1.92086014e-01, 1.15276068e-01, 4.01797967e-02,
       7.08805229e-02, 3.99687904e-03, 6.68727677e-03, 0.00000000e+00,
       1.02021005e-02, 5.06637671e-03, 7.97826949e-03, 5.64939616e-03,
       0.00000000e+00, 9.09583016e-04, 1.84022196e-03, 9.29047900e-04,
       1.74001682e-04, 8.55362503e-05, 2.32440522e-03, 4.65023589e-04,
       4.13278579e-03, 3.68265995e-03, 1.78503960e-02, 8.33035943e-03,
       6.94454768e-03, 1.75988171e-02, 5.40933687e-04, 7.51299294e-03,
       6.07480929e-03, 2.28627732e-03, 1.32219786e-03, 1.92990938e-01,
       1.18517448e-03, 1.61377248e-03, 5.72167000e-04, 1.34920904e-03,
       5.41685180e-03, 0.00000000e+00, 9.16416279e-03, 1.05824472e-02,
       3.07744966e-03, 3.07152204e-03, 5.06657379e-03, 5.21819782e-03,
       0.00000000e+00, 7.49534136e-03, 2.83936918e-03, 8.62398812e-03,
       5.78720378e-03, 5.37536831e-03, 2.99744077e-03, 1.87247908e-03,
       4.87696805e-04, 1.58422357e-03, 2.20761597e-03, 5.57396015e-03,
       1.17619435e-03, 1.87465473e-03, 4.08710965e-03, 6.73508851e-04,
       6.02887867e-03, 2.38887308e-03, 4.52029746e-03, 7.28018074e-05,
       5.13158297e-04, 2.66768058e-04, 0.00000000e+00, 3.28378333e-04,
       0.00000000e+00, 8.55362503e-05, 0.00000000e+00, 7.89886262e-04,
       1.84475320e-04, 1.37879652e-03, 0.00000000e+00, 3.27800552e-04,
       1.95189232e-04, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 9.00792536e-04, 0.00000000e+00, 2.20606426e-04,
       5.82787439e-04, 4.85000896e-04, 5.33409400e-04, 0.00000000e+00,
       8.75840665e-04, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       4.65546160e-04, 3.37472507e-04, 2.50837357e-04, 2.52474592e-04,
       0.00000000e+00, 1.47818105e-04, 3.06829767e-04, 3.73651596e-04,
       1.58778645e-04, 4.40566013e-03, 8.55362503e-05, 2.51672361e-04])
```

which is not correct as I only have 13 features. I know the reason for this is OneHotencoding.

How can get the actual feature importances?

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid you **cannot** get importances for your initial features here. Your decision tree does not know anything about them; the only thing it sees and knows about is the encoded ones, and nothing else.

You may want to try the [*permutation* importance](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/permutation_importance.html) instead, which has several advantages over the tree-based feature importance; it is also easily applicable to pipelines - see [Permutation importance using a Pipeline in SciKit-Learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62106204/permutation-importance-using-a-pipeline-in-scikit-learn).

Comment: Yes, I tried permutation importances and it works. So, whenever we have to onehot encode some features, feature importances is basically impossible to interpret?

Comment: @chesslad Yes; plus, classical feature importance measures have not been very useful in practice, since different importance measures can give inconsistent results - see https://towardsdatascience.com/interpretable-machine-learning-with-xgboost-9ec80d148d27 .

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, the importance of a data column can be obtained by summing the importances of all the features that are based on it. Identifying column-to-feature mappings could be a little difficult to do by hand, but you can always use automated tools for that.

For example, the [SkLearn2PMML](https://github.com/jpmml/sklearn2pmml) package can translate Scikit-Learn pipelines to PMML representation, and perform various analyses and transformations while doing so. The calculation of aggregate feature importances is well supported.

```
from sklearn2pmml import sklearn2pmml
from sklearn2pmml.pipeline import PMMLPipeline

pipeline = PMMLPipeline([
  ("preprocessor", preprocessor),
  ("classifier", clf)
])
pipeline.fit(X, y)
# Re-map the dynamic attribute to a static pickleable attribute
clf.pmml_feature_importances_ = clf.feature_importances_

sklearn2pmml(pipeline, "PipelineWithImportances.pmml.xml")
```